# Move-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move recordings from my source location to individual folders within my destination location if the recording name contains the phone number that matches with a folder. This works most of the time but for some reason, I get a lot of these errors

```
Move-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Destination'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\move_calls.ps1:34 char:50
+         Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Path
+                                                  ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

This is my "working" script so far, it looks for phone numbers after +1 and matches that with corresponding folders. a file looks like `Inbound_20210115-080548_+11234567890_Automatic.mp3`

```
#set source and destination directory
$source = "C:\path\to\source"
$destination = "C:\path\to\destination"

#Populate with all folders in client directory
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Directory -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

#Filter source for mp3 files
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File -Filter *.mp3|
ForEach-Object {
        
    #For each file in source directory, match the phone number
    $_.BaseName -match "\+1(\d*)_"
    $File = $Matches[1]
    #If matching directory is found in destination move the recording over to that folder
    If ($Path = $Folders | Where-Object {$_ -match $File}) {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Path
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$path` is a collection. If you want it’s first item use `$path[0]`

Comment: I would use $path[0] after the -Destination ?

Comment: @AdminOfThings this seemed to not work, im looking to match `$File` against the collection of folders located within the destination path so then when there is a match, the file will move to that matched folder

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things to note :)

```
#set source and destination directory
$source = "C:\path\to\source"
$destination = "C:\path\to\destination"

#Populate with all folders in client directory
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Directory -Recurse # | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
                                                                # Do not expand and only take FullName. Take whole
                                                                # [directoryinfo] object so you can use other properties later

#Filter source for mp3 files
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File -Filter *.mp3 |
    ForEach-Object {

        #For each file in source directory, match the phone number
        if ($_.BaseName -match "\+1(\d*)_") { # Only continue on to move file if regex matches
            $File = $Matches[1]

            #If matching directory is found in destination move the recording over to that folder
            If ($Path = ,($Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $File }) ) {  # Here we take advantage of having
                                                                        # [directoryinfo] objects by using the Name property.
                                                                        # This way we don't accidentally match on some other
                                                                        # folder in the parent path. (unless you want this, then change
                                                                        # $_.Name to $_.FullName)
                                                                        ## Careful when using variable after -match as
                                                                        ## $File may contain special characters that need to
                                                                        ## be escaped. May be better to use $_ -like "*$File*"
                                                                        ### ,() around $Folders | Where-Object... guarentees you
                                                                        ### always get an array back whether there is only one
                                                                        ### match or many.  This makes our next line more
                                                                        ### likely to succeed.

                # Since $Path is now always an array use array index of 0 to get first item
                # if you expect ever there could be more than 1 decide how you want to handle this.
                # Also items in $Path are [directoryinfo] objects because we changed $Folders above
                # so use FullName property
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Path[0].FullName -WhatIf
            }
        }
    }
```